# Spring Data Rest + Spring Security: @Secured not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-rest

I'm building an application using `Spring Data Rest`, `Spring Boot` and `Spring Security`. I need to use `@Secured` annotations on methods and I've configured `Spring Security` in the following way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // @formatter:off
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .securityContext().securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository())
                    .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage(RestPath.Errors.ROOT + RestPath.Errors.FORBIDDEN)
                    .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
    // @formatter:on

    @Bean
    public SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
        return new ApiUserSecurityContextRepository();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new ApiUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new ProviderManager(Collections.singletonList(authenticationProvider()));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() throws Exception {
        final DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

This type of configuration works well for regular MVC controllers and returns 403 when I try to access them. For example, the following controller security works:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = RestPath.Configs.SLASH_TEST, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)
@Secured({"ROLE_USER"})
public ResponseEntity test(@RequestParam(value = RestParam.DB_TEST, required = false) final boolean dbTest) throws ApplicationAvailabilityException {
    final AppTestData appTestData = configService.testAppAvailability(dbTest);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(projectionFactory.createProjection(AppTestProjection.class, appTestData));
}
```

However, when I try to use @Secured annotation over a rest repository - it does NOT, e.g.:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = Shop.COLLECTION_NAME, path = RestResourceRel.SHOPS, excerptProjection = StandardShopProjection.class)
@Secured({"ROLE_USER"})
public interface RestShopRepository extends MongoRepository<Shop, String> {

    @Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
    @Override
    Shop findOne(String s);
}
```

`ApiUserSecurityContextRepository` is getting called for both of the methods, but only a custom MVC controller is get to the end of chain and I can check that it accesses `vote()` method in `RoleVoter` class for granting access.
As an example, I've checked [Spring Data Rest + Spring Security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/security) sample, so `@Secured` or `@PreAuthorize` annotations should work with `Spring Data Rest`. Any ideas why they don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue. The problem was in the following, I had another `ShopRepository` in different application module, which was not annotated with `@RepositoryRestResource` and it was the one which was used when accessing it using REST.

The following line of configuration in custom `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter` fixed the exploration of repositories which need to be exposed, so only annotated ones are exposed now:

```
config.setRepositoryDetectionStrategy(RepositoryDetectionStrategy.RepositoryDetectionStrategies.ANNOTATED);
```

After that I could not access the resource at all using REST, so I've figured out that it is not visible to `Spring`. I just had to enable Mongo repositories on API level with annotation `@EnableMongoRepositories`.

Comment: How are you accessing secured RepositoryRestResource from your security modules? Let's say you want to query user by username from UserDetailsService - you want to do it in kind of god mode instead using credentials provided by HTTP session.

Comment: @Piotr not sure I've understood your question correctly. Why credentials provided by HTTP session would not work?

Comment: Let's say user with role USER is doing a request. You want to look his in user repository in some security filter method like loadUserByUsername, so you call findByUsername query method. But that method is annonated with hasRole(ADMIN) which leads to unauthorized access since spring is executing it with role USER credentials. Is it clear?